# Wordpress Making Entire Page Opaque when hovering over menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a request from a client and have no idea if this is even possible. We are making use of Uber Menu and when someone hovers over the menu, the rest of the website must become opaque or darker or must fade.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called Overlay. See there for example (click Example, then click on an image) : http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/
Or : http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at CSS solutions, for example:

http://faavorite.com/faave/73082894943387648 (the fiddle at the bottom)

or, adapting this to your needs:

http://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/

Comment: Here, this is a cleaner example of the first link: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisjlebron/BZtFs/ . The magic happens in the last two rule sets. A couple of caveats though: **1.** CSS transitions and CSS box-shadows are not supported in all browsers, so you'll need a fallback for older/less capable browsers. **2.** Animating box-shadows in CSS can be slow and costly (i.e. CPU intensive), so that's something to keep in mind.